# Laravel: Set timestamp on database connection laravel mysql

Tags: laravel-5

I would like to understand how to set the timestamp on every connection to the mysql database connection through laravel Is there any configuration which helps in achieving this.

Comment: Whenever you create the table migration add  $table->timestamps();  at every tables up function in your migration file It will add created_at and updated_at two columns in your respective table.

Answer (score 0):

Eloquent automatically updates the `updated_at` attribute whenever a model is updated. Just add the timestamps to your migration, like this:

```
$table->timestamps();
```

`created_at` and `updated_at` fields will then be added to your table and eloquent will use them automatically.

[Full example from the laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/migrations#migration-structure):

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateFlightsTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('flights', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('airline');
            $table->timestamps(); // <<< Adds created_at and updated_at
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::drop('flights');
    }
}
```